# PHP: how to keep I/O accessible in parent after pcntl_fork()'s child has completed?

Tags: php, forking

I'm using PHP and pcntl_fork().  The idea is that the parent forks and pauses for the child to complete; the child does a task then terminates; the parent can check the return code for the task or the status of the child process and continue accordingly.

(The task is isolated from the main parent by forking, to ensure the parent can clean up nicely if the task hits an untrappable runtime issue, such as corrupt "include" files or missing key libraries, hence the fork, basically I'm implementing simple process isolation for the hopefully-rare occasion an untrappable condition might cause a problem)

So the problem is that after pcntl_fork() both processes share the same STDXXX I/O descriptors, so as soon as the child finishes its task, the I/O it's using get closed as usual, and so they are closed for the parent as well, meaning that things like echo() used to continue interactions by the parent, suddenly stop working too.

I'm following a tip on php.net and using posix kill -9 in the child instead of exit, so that the child terminates without closing IO shared with (and needed by) the parent, but is there a neater way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hmm, Unix file descriptors are _not_ shared across a fork(), and neither are PHP IO objects... So the cause is more complex than that.

Answer (score 0):

Before the `pcntl_fork()` you can "dup" the file desired file descriptors by opening for example `php://stdout` and `php://stderr`, or `php://fd/3`. See
php [protocols](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php).

---

Note that when a child closes a file descriptor, it is **not** closed in the parent. After a fork the processes share the same **pointer** to open files, but you still be able to echo from the parent after the child has exited.

Comment: This sounds promising, but areas like sessions and the required manipulation of dup'ed STDXXX descriptors are a bit beyond my current knowledge area and the pages (on php.net and opengropup.org) aren't as clear to me as I'd hope. Could you explain how to do this with a short "outline" example? It would help a lot.

Comment: @Stilez on rereading your post I'm not sure why you should need to do anything special, as `close()` in a child does not affect the parent copy of a   file descriptor. `pcntl_fork()` is supposed to call the real system `fork()` which effectively does `dup()` on open files.

Comment: I looked but php.net doesn't seem to recognise close() as a command? What is clear is that when I replace exit() or die() in the child with a POSIX self-kill -9 the parent is able to continue output with echo, when I don't it can't, so the cleanup during normal child exiting must somehow be closing or affecting STDXXX descriptors used by the parent. Is it possible to post a short outline of a way to exit the child differently, or dup or "separate" or distangle the descriptors so that the child exiting doesn't have that effect? It would really help.

Comment: @Stilez I tried a small cgi with the child doing exit, and the parent was able to continue doing echo (with PHP/5.5.24 on linux), so I cant help further with your situation. Perhaps your child is sending back a `Content-Length:` header with the number of bytes the child wrote. Most browsers will respect this length and not read beyond it, even if the parent php did manage to write more data.